# How to force compiler allocation on the stack indenpendent from the compiler optimization

Tags: c

I defined the following function:

```
   static void Init(char Port, char param2)
    {
      Handle *pdhandle = &GLOBAL_Handles[Port];
      CallbacksTab tab_Callbacks =
         {
          toto,  //ptr of function
          tata,
          titi,
         };
```

the table tab_Callbacks is only used inside this function and i would like force the allocation of this table on the stack to safe flash space.

Compilation without optimization performs the allocation on the stack, but when i used compilation optimized for size, the allocation is done on flash space !

I want to know if there is any C key word to force allocation on stack independant of the compilator optimization ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: C doesn't have a "stack". You need to consult your platform documentation for details like that; perhaps there's a vendor extension that allows you to control things like that.

Comment: The compiler can only put data into flash if no writes are performed. It might be some ugly hack but you could try to assign one of these values at runtime instead of using it as initiliazer.

Comment: What is the question? Is it "How to force compiler allocation on the stack" or "i would like force the allocation of this table on the stack to safe flash space"? These seem contradicting to me.

Comment: If the tab is created "on the stack" then the values for it must be copied in from somewhere... where else would that be if not "flash space" ?

Comment: Do you changes those values? My best guess is that they could be at the text segment. You could try starting one of the values as NULL, then set it to the final value at another function, but as others pointed out, you will have to check the platform documentation if you want to be sure.

Comment: @M.M From .data or .bss? Given that it is function pointers, they are not necessarily read-only.

Comment: Either the compiler generates it at compile time or the compiler will have to generate code to generate it. The code to generate the table will almost certainly be bigger than a pregenerated table. So the solution you're looking for will actually make your problem worse.

Comment: Ok sorry my question was stupid, because the contents of the varaible must be stored somewhere so inside the flash